# I can't update from a view with an outer join

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join, sql-view

I'm learning about SQL with MySQL and I have a problem when I try to update from a view with an outer join

Here is an example :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
  id tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  t2_id tinyint(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  col3 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO t1 (id, t2_id, col3) VALUES
(1, 1, 'a'),
(2, 1, 'b'),
(3, 2, '3'),
(4, 2, '7'),
(5, NULL, '!');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2 (
  id tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  col2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO t2 (id, col2) VALUES
(1, 'Character'),
(2, 'Number');

CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW v_t1_details
AS SELECT t1.id, t2.col2, t1.col3
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id;
```

I'm on MySQL 5.7 (5.7.14 and 5.7.19, completely uninstalled and reinstalled between the two versions) and here is what happens when I use this query :

```
UPDATE v_t1_details SET col3 = 'c' WHERE id = 2;

#1288 - The target table v_t1_details of the UPDATE is not updatable
```

I know it's not possible to use an outer join with an insert request but I have not seen anything like that in my course or on the MySQL Documentation for an update, so I'd like to know why it's not working.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update a SQL VIEW - well generally speaking

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)

> In a database, a view is the result set of a stored query on the data,
>   which the database users can query just as they would in a persistent
>   database collection object. This pre-established query command is kept
>   in the database dictionary. Unlike ordinary base tables in a
>   relational database, a view does not form part of the physical schema:
>   as a result set, it is a virtual table computed or collated
>   dynamically from data in the database when access to that view is
>   requested.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/639239/Creating-and-Usage-of-View-in-SQL

> A view is virtual, the data from a view is not stored physically. It
>   is a set of queries that, when applied to one or more tables, is
>   stored in the database as an object. A view encapsulates the name of
>   the table. A virtual table contains column and data from multiple
>   tables.

but thanks to @Thibaut, in fact you can with mySQL with certain limitations

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html

> With respect to insertability (being updatable with INSERT
>   statements), an updatable view is insertable if it also satisfies
>   these additional requirements for the view columns:
>
> There must be no duplicate view column names.
>
> The view must contain all columns in the base table that do not have a
>   default value.
>
> The view columns must be simple column references. They must not be
>   expressions, such as these:

Comment: You can update a view on MySQL [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html)

Comment: wow.... MySQL has extended its functions but can't even get a row_number feature available. what are the odds.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to respect the conditions for the insertion to be able to update also ?

Comment: You to follow the rules for you to update a view in mySql

Comment: start with the first one. all columns should have the same name